# Difference between address/location bar and search bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to buil firefox search plugin something like instantfox. I already have it working in search bar with my search engine image. This is my first attempt so I am not sure how I can do this and google did not help me point in a right direction.

1. Is it possible to create search plugin that will work for both address bar and search bar. If yes then how I can do that? is there any properties in bootstrap file that I have to mention?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you consider a "search plugin that work for both address bar and search bar"...

Starting with Firefox 23, the address bar will use the selected search engine for non-urls. See [bug 738818](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738818). Before Firefox 23, this was controlled by the keyword.URL preference.

Also there are [special bookmarks for keyword searches](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar).

Lastly, you may implement nsIAutoCompleteSearch in an add-on and set the address-bar to use your implementation.